# Do envelopes in DocuSign developer accounts disappear?

Tags: docusignapi

some of the signing documents I created in my Docusign developer environment seem to no longer be accessible. Were they perhaps auto-purged from the dev environment? Is there a log somewhere to find info about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the developer account is for testing and demonstration purposes and envelopes are removed 30 days after they were created.

You can find more details about this in this article - https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-long-does-DocuSign-store-my-documents?language=en_US&rsc_301